What is the live-action WWII film G.I. Robot was watching in Creature Commandos S01E03?
In Creature Commandos Season 1, Episode 3, "Cheers to the Tin Man," a flashback scene shows G.I. Robot watching TV in the home of the person who acquired him, Sam Fitzgibbon. They are watching a live-action war film that appears to be from the 1960s or 1970s and is set during World War II. Given what was revealed of Sam later

 (that he's a Nazi),

I'm curious to know what this film was.


This is The Dirty Dozen (1967)
You can see the clip in the snippet below, starting about thirty seconds in.





James Gunn has repeatedly mentioned being a fan of the movie and wishing to pay homage to the film across all of his own productions, frequently referencing scenes that he's enjoyed.

“I love the John Ostrander Suicide Squad comics. I love The Dirty Dozen, the movie. Loved it as a kid, was one of my favorite movies. And then when Adam Glass’s New 52 run of Suicide Squad came out, I was reminded by how cool it was and I just always wanted to tell a super villain story. I just like the idea of this Dirty Dozen with super villains, with crappy super villains.

James Gunn Reveals His Love For ‘The Suicide Squad’ And The Future Of Moviegoing


@A.J. - I'm not sure why you've locked the other answer. His was correct but very sparse. I added in some details I thought would be useful. OP (evidently) wasn't happy with the changes and rolled it back, so I created a new answer.
